# Does Lagrange interpolation work for complex numbers?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, lagrange-interpolation

I am attempting a question that regarding Polynomial and remainder theorem with quadratic divisors ( $x^2 + 1 $) and ($x^2 + 2$) specifically. The resulting remainder is supposed to be a degree 3 polynomial. However, since the quadratic divisors have imaginary roots, would it be possible to use Lagrange interpolation for complex numbers? e.g. R(i) = 3i+2, R(-i) = -3i+2 and (with tedious manipulation) obtain the answer.
Is there a better method to compute, and is it Mathematically correct to use Lagrange interpolation to determine the polynomial with complex roots?

Comment: Yes, it works over complex numbers. Here $R(z)=3z+2$, or $-z^2(3z+2)$ for degree $3$. What is the original question you are "attempting"? I am sure it can be solved differently.

Comment: when P(x) is divided by x^2 + 1 and x^2 +2, the remainder is 3x+2 and 2x+1 respectively. R(x) is the remainder when P(x) is divided by (x^2+1)(x^2+2), find R(1)